# table marked as crash in wampserver

Tags: wamp

my database table will crash when my row is above 15,955. If I try to repair the table it will tell me Number of rows changed from 15958 to 15955. Please guys, how can I resolved this

table repair, but I always have data lost

Comment: Please show us a `SHOW CREATE TABLE the_table`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or mariaDB Wampserver has both?